# Disable a date in datepicker for 24hrs

Tags: php, jquery, datepicker, timepicker

I want to disable a date which is 24hours from the current timestamp in the date-picker.
For e.g, if the current date-time is 6th June 12:00 PM then the next date i.e 7th June should be disabled till 12:00 PM on the 7th June. I have two dropdowns in the form, one for selecting the date and the other for selecting the time slot which is a time-picker.

So as per the above scenario, if 7th june has time-slots such as 8:00AM-10:00AM, 10:00AM-12:00PM and so on..then it should disable the time slots also accordingly.

I am using PHP code. Can anyone please help?

Below code i am trying to get the date which needs to be blocked:

```
$booking_closed_from = date('Y-m-d');
$booking_closed_till = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 day'));
```

Now I am passing this $booking_closed_till date to the date-picker to disable it.

But I am not sure how to enable the date after 24hours has passed. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Please share your attempts, such that others can see where your code is going wrong

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'd recommend you read [ask] and then [edit] your question accordingly. We can't help you debug descriptions.

Comment: You don't need to manually enable anything. If the date that needs to be disabled is generated dynamically, it simply won't be sent as disabled the next day.

Comment: @El_Vanja did not understand your point. Do you mean the date will automatically enable once the 24hours has passed?

Comment: I would assume so from the information you have given us. If your datepicker works by disabling the supplied date and that date is dynamic, it will only disable that date (it has no mechanism of remembering what it disabled yesterday). So if today is the 2nd of the month, it will disable the 3rd. Once date switches to 3rd, the calculated date will become the 4th, hence the 3rd will no longer be sent as the date to be disabled.

Comment: Think about it - if you run the exact code you've shown above again tomorrow, what would be the result? Unless you keep the page with the datepicker open in your browser for 24 hours (unlikely, I'd say) then, you're going to be re-loading that page again tomorrow when you need it. At that point, it'll run the PHP again, which will then use tomorrow's date to do the calculation.

Comment: But i am trying to explain is i have a timepicker too.. so lets say for example code runs on 02/06/2021 3PM so it will disable 03/06/2021. But if the time-slots available for 03/06/2021 are 1PM to 2PM, 2PM to 3PM, 4PM to 5 PM then how can i disable the date for 24hours and show only the time-slots that fall after completion of 24hours?

Comment: Ok that didn't seem to be the focus of your question - it was a little bit vague (You originally asked about re-enabling the datepicker after 24 hours, it was not really clear how the timepicker was involved). But why would that be a problem? What kind of timepicker are you using? How are you passing the information about disabled slots to it currently? Why can't you tell it to disable the sepcific hours you want? None of this is clear, we'll need more information.

Comment: Currently i am not getting any solution to disable time slots in timepicker as through the the dynamic code i am just able to get the date to be disabled. i am not getting the time when the 24 hours end so that i can disable the time slots..Can you please help me on this?

Comment: First please show the timepicker you are using. Is it native HTML5 timepicker? Or something enabled using Javascript? We can't tell you how to interact with something when we don't know what it is

Comment: `through the the dynamic code i am just able to get the date to be disabled`...well you could start by getting the current time as well as the date. And then you just need to go forward 24 hours from that.

Comment: You can assume its a simple select dropdown with timeslots option.

Comment: Please share more details. The current code does not "block" anything, and the code doesn't contain any information about how you configured the date picker so far

Comment: You'll need Javascript then. Detect when the user has changed the selected date in the datepicker. If today's date is selected, then remove / disable all options after the current time (you can also get this using JS). If tomorrow's date is selected, remove / disable all options _before_ the current time. You can't do this with PHP because it depends on what the user currently selected in the datepicker.

Comment: ok @ADyson thanks i will try to implement this and check